# Suddenly unable to build android studio project error: cannot access zzbcc

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I am getting following error in my android studio project:

> Error:(77, 40) error: cannot access zzbcc class file for
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcc not found Error:Execution failed
>   for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

It appeared suddenly. The issue is in one of the file which uses firebase authentication. If I comment it then appears in another file which is using Map.

**Edit1:**

> > dependencies {
> >         compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
> >         androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',
> >     {
> >             exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
> >         })
> >
> > ```
> > compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
> > compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.2, 3.99.99]'
> > compile 'com.github.pinball83:masked-edittext:1.0.3'
> > compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.+'
> > compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.2'
> > compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.2'
> > compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.2'
> > compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.2.2'
> > compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.2.2'
> > compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.2.2'
> > compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.2.2'
> > compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.2.2'
> > compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.0.0'
> > compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
> > compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.+'
> > compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.+'
> > compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
> > compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
> > compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
> > compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
> > compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
> > compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.+'
> > compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.+'
> > compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.+'
> > testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'  }  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
> > ```

I am quite sure the error is not because of any code change, as it was working but when I opened it after some days it stopped working. There should be some problem in dependencies.

Comment: Please show relevant code and your build.gradle.

Comment: please check my dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Remove this dependency from your build:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.0.0'
```

This is a very old version of Firebase-UI.  You should be using the [instructions here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/) instead.  Also consider updating your version of the Firebase SDKs, and make sure that there is a match between the version of Firebase-UI and the SDKs as shown in the table in the docs I referenced.

Comment: Sorry, bad paste.  Updated.

Comment: I have updated it to firebase-ui 2.2.0 and firebase 11.0.4 but it is still not working. I also tried firebase-ui 3.0 and latest firbase but then I was getting lots of error because of changes in recycleview. I don't want to make so many changes right now

Comment: You will have to make changes because you can't use the old Firebase-UI library with the new Firebase SDKs.