# when i try for notification i'm getting error: cannot access Hide

Tags: android

[image]

when trying to add notification in mt app im getting this error 
    i tried [Suddenly unable to build android studio project error: cannot access zzbcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47837264/suddenly-unable-to-) 
    build-android-studio-project-error-cannot-access-zzbcc
    and also [Cannot access ActivityCompatApi23 class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46928223/cannot-access-) 
    activitycompatapi23-class?rq=1 but no use

Comment: Can you show your full code please

Comment: @kavya please detail "when i try for notification"

Comment: add your code  for more info

Comment: i'm referring https://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-1/    added same in my app

Comment: **Please post the code that you have trouble with**

Comment: Where you able to fix it, I am seeing the same issue     implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:16.2.0"

Comment: Any update on this? I get the same issue while I try to update Places API. I think there is something wrong with keeping new Places API gradle and gms play service together! Any guess?